# Variadic templates argument fowarding

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Say I have a function `foo()` with takes advantage of c++ variadic templates feature. Now, what's the difference between these implementations:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
whatever(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&... args) {
whatever(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
whatever(&args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
whatever(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    whatever(args...);
}
```

`foo` gets *copies* of `args` and passes them to `whatever` as l-values.

```
template<typename... Args> 
void foo(Args&... args) {
     whatever(args...);
}
```

`foo` gets l-value references to `args` and passes them to `whatever` as l-values.

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    whatever(&args...);
}
```

`foo` gets *copies* of `args` and passes them to `whatever` as pointers to l-values. Be careful of object lifetimes here.

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
    whatever(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

`foo` gets *forwarding* references to `args`. Whether they are l-values or r-values depends on what happens at the call site. They are then perfect-forwarded to `whatever`, preserving their reference type. Scott Meyers originally called these "universal" references, but *forwarding* reference is the preferred terminology now.

Answer (score 2):

The first one takes its arguments by value. The second one takes its arguments by lvalue reference (so non-`const` rvalues cannot be used). The third one also takes its arguments by value, but passes pointers to `whatever`. The fourth one takes its arguments by forwarding reference and perfect-forwards them to `whatever`.

There is nothing magical about the variadic templates; the rules are the same as if there were only one argument.